# Angular 4: Cannot find newly create module

Tags: angular

I just did a simple ng create module called "core" in my app directory, in the same level as app.module. But when I try to use it from app.module.ts, I get: 'Cannot find module'

```
import { CoreModule } from "core";
```

Here is my tree:

```
app/
    app.module.ts
    core/
        core.module.ts
```

Comment: I don't get it. `core` or `Common`?

Comment: Sorry, typo. CoreModule- that's the name of my custom module

Comment: `... from "./core/core.module";`.

Comment: @Connors- Thanks that worked. I'm new to Angular. Didn't realize you need to import the file. I've seen other places where they just import the directory.

Comment: Just additional FYI: `import { CoreModule } from 'core'` is not importing the directory `core`.  It is importing from a module named `core`.  It will look in `node_modules` and not `./core`.  You can do `import { CoreModule } from './core'` which will import the directory but it will require the directory to contain a file named `index.ts` that specifies what in the directory to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current setup (no `index.ts` in the `core` directory) you will need to do:

```
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
```

If you want you can create a file `index.ts` in the `core` directory with the contents:

```
export * from './core';
```

Then you can do:

```
import { CoreModule } from './core';
```

The purpose of the `index.ts` file is to give you control over what gets exported from a directory so that you can, for example, not expose your `spec.ts` files.